# Laravel shows wrong storage path

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project in my localhost Linux server. now I change my os to windows. Now my avatar image seems broken my storage path is

```
 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

When i hit myprojectname/storage it shows linux path`(/var/www/html/testadmin/storage/app/public`) ie my previous project path.i don't know why this happen.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: may be clear config `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: i have clear it but same @JigneshJoisar

Answer (score 0):

is posible that the symlink of your storage/public folder was wrong, you can review if this is pointing to the correct folder
Use the ls -l command to check whether a given file is a symbolic link, and to find the file or directory that symbolic link point to.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

The first character “l”, indicates that the file is a symlink. The “->” symbol shows the file the symlink points to.

The rm command removes given files and directories.
To delete a symlink, invoke the rm command followed by the symbolic link name as an argument:

```
rm symlink_name
```

create a new symlink to the storage public folder

```
php artisan storage:link
```